# extending nested interface generated by supabase

Tags: typescript, supabase

I have the following Typescript interface generated by [Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/generating-types)

```
export interface definitions {  
  Users: {
    /** Format: uuid */
    id: string;
    /**
     * Format: timestamp with time zone
     * @default now()
     */
    created_at?: string;
    /**
     * Format: uuid
     * @description Note:
     * This is a Primary Key.<pk/>
     */
  };
  Content: {
    /**
     * Format: uuid
     * @description Note:
     * This is a Primary Key.<pk/>
     */
    id: string;
    /**
     * Format: timestamp with time zone
     * @default now()
     */
    created_at?: string;
    /** Format: text */
    name: string;
    /** Format: text */
    description: string;
  };
}
```

This interface must not be modified as it is auto-generated.

I usually use it like this on queries:

```
import { definitions } from "../types/supabase";
const id = 1
let { data, error } = await supabase
  .from<definitions["Users"]>("Users").select("created_at")
  .eq("id", id);
```

However for this query I need to extend my interface:

```
let { data: Content, error } = await supabase
  .from<ContentAndUsers>("Content")
  .select(`*, Users (id, created_at)`)
  .eq("id", id);
```

I tried creating the interface but it gives me TS error:

```
interface UserContentCombo extends definitions["Content"] {
    ...definitions["Users"]
}
```

what is the correct syntax?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the error says:

> An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with
> optional type arguments

So to give it an identifier and fix it you can define an intermediate type:

```
type userDefinitions = definitions['User'];
```

And then use that identifier:

```
interface UserContentCombo extends userDefinitions {}
```

No need of using the spread operator

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgE2HWQRgQiQGc4BvOOAKHoFVK1KAuWp+uAegBUAuADFoAW0wwuAVxkJ8cAXx70FXSjCjIA5gG5V-IYaWiJUrmXHBNmcWDgB3UgAs4VvAC8KwE8IAChFgyADbwSBCOABQAlH4qvHDYUMBSwPgA+lIA-BpaugaJggJ+ZlCS0nByCqWBNskIYGQUcAByEKgcpQAqLgjU-XCYcAAK2pJQAJ5wANLAkwB0ADxgANZ8AHzxPAC+hXAAwhSoKFw0hsWlYuUWVfL4tYSUDU3kSG0dwF2Jpr2Dg8MxggJtM5osVustj9lIZ1HBNNokPoLsZoWUKpZgTYYHYHM4YG4PHBvEhfGi6sEwnAItE4tCErxkqlUJkcnlEciikJ0bdUCB4DDEkg7F94fkkft6MUeZU+QKGfQni9mkh2QVdgYdgwGDBJmA8DI2FAACJEEgq6gAXgIZqQpDelAA2gByVjsZ0AXQMyFQGBweAAgnBQCd8NRDWhTcQ7RbaFqGNgKJoqkauEHrTQdkA)

Comment: You don't incorporate `definitions["Content"]` into `UserContentCombo`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a type containing all the properties from both `Users` and `Content`, this would probably be the shortest way:

```
type UserContentCombo = definitions["Content"] & definitions["Users"]
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgE2HWQRgQiQGc4BvOOAKHoFVK1KAuWp%20uAegBUAuADFoAW0wwuAVxkJ8cAXx70FXSjCjIA5gG5V-IYaWiJUrmXHBNmcWDgB3UgAs4VvAC8KwE8IAChFgyADbwSBCOABQAlH4qvHDYUMBSwPgA%20lIA-BpaugaJggJ%20ZlCS0nByCqWBNskIYGQUcAByEKgcpQAqLgjU-XCYcAAK2pJQAJ5wANLAkwB0ADxgANZ8AHzxPAC%20hXAAwhSoKFw0hsWlYuUWVfL4tYSUDU3kSG0dwF2Jpr2Dg8MxggJtM5osVustj9lIZ1HBNNokPoLsZoWUKpZgTYYHYHM4YG4PHBvEhfGi6sEwnAItE4tCErxkqlUJkcnlEciikJ0bdUCB4DDEkg7F94fkkft6MUeZU%20QKGfQni9mkh2QVdgYdgwGDBJmA8Kw0EcUMAUEdxAAjCBwAC8BCIJBVlAA2gAiY0nGCugC6cAAZPbiEhSG8Xa7DVBKD6gA)